# unix construct "or" condition on a filename

Tags: shell, unix, if-statement

I have a shell script where I pass (2) parameters, one to pass a dbname, the other to call one of (2) filenames. I want to check if either filename exists, then proceed with calling that script, else exit because the user can enter the wrong string and construct `my_foo.sql` which I don't want. I don't think I have the condition for setting "or" correctly since putting the correct param still produces error. Is there a better way to write this?

Here is what I have so far.

```
#/usr/bin/ksh

if [ $# != 2 ]; then
   echo "Usage: test.sh <dbname> <test|live>" 2>&1
   exit 1
fi

# Check actual file name
CHKSCRIPT1=/tmp/my_test.sql;
CHKSCRIPT2=/tmp/my_live.sql;

if [ -f "CHKSCRIPT1" ] || [ -f "CHKSCRIPT2" ]
   then
       /bin/sqlplus -s foo/bar @/my_$2.sql
   else
       echo "Correct sql script does not exist. Enter test or live"
       exit 1
fi
```

Comment: If the user enters "live", does it matter if /tmp/my_test.sql exists (and vice versa)?

Comment: yes, either of the file must exists. i need 2 files to be present, but let's say the user enters 'foo', and the name of the file is my_foo.sql, then exit since its not the one of the files.

Comment: Either, but not both. If the user enters "live", `my_test.sql` doesn't appear to be used. It seems you only really need to check if `/tmp/my_$2.sql` exists.

Comment: if I only need to check if `/tmp/my_$2.sql` exists, it will still be the wrong file if the user doesn't enter either "test" or "live" that's why i added those `CHKSCRIPT1` and `CHKSCRIPT2` variables. Either way, using this '||' operator doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the problem you had with expanding the parameters, you should separate what the user types from what files need to exist. If the user enters "live", the only thing that matters is whether or not `/tmp/my_live.sql` exists. If the user enters "injection_attack", your script should not execute `/tmp/my_injection_attack.sql` (which presumably was created without your knowledge). The right thing to do is to first verify that a valid command was entered, *then* check if the appropriate file exists.

```
if [ $# != 2 ]; then
   echo "Usage: test.sh <dbname> <test|live>" 2>&1
   exit 1
fi

case $2 in
    test|live)
       filename="/tmp/my_{$2}.sql"
       ;;
    *) echo "Must enter test or live"
       exit 1
       ;;
esac

if [ -f "$filename" ]; then
    /bin/sqlplus -s foo/bar @/my_$2.sql
else
    echo "SQL script $filename does not exist."
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that you're not referencing your variables correctly:

```
if [ -f "$CHKSCRIPT1" ] || [ -f "$CHKSCRIPT2" ]
   ...
fi
```

*edit: Per @chepner, you shouldn't use `-o`*

Comment: Don't use `-o`; even the POSIX standard recommends the first version.

Comment: if its not -o, then what should I use? If you would show an example please.

Comment: I already have. The only problem with your script was how you called your variables. Your or logic was valid.

Comment: got it. thanks. I just noticed that $ sign. thank you.